# numPy - Creating array of function values

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to create an array whose values are the values return from a function.

I also want that the value previously received will fill in the function, creating the next element in the array.
It should look somwthing like that:

```
a = numpy.array(function(x), function(function(x)), ...)
```

instead of:

```
  arr = np.array(x)
  for i in range(n):
     new_result = function(x)
     x = new_result
     b = np.array(x)
     arr = np.vstack((arr, b))
```

The function is capable taking the value created in previous iteration. Array length is long so it is impossible doing it manually.

Is there any way doing it without a for loop?

Comment: Collect rows in a list and do one `vstack` at the end,

Comment: But how can I apply the function again and again without the for loop?

Comment: You can't.  'again and again' means some sort of loop or iteration, doesn't it?  When we talk about eliminating for loops in `numpy` we really mean performing the iteration in compiled code, using the provided building blocks.  Plus your action is inherently serial - the 2nd row depends on the 1st and so on.  Most of the fast `numpy` operations are by nature parallel - conceptually operating on the whole array 'at-once'.

Comment: Some `ufuncs` have an accumulate method.  `np.add.accumulate`, e.g. `np.cumsum` is most widely used.  That's the closest `numpy` comes to applying an operation sequentially on some input array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a while loop is an alternative to a for loop.

```
arr = np.array(x)
i = 0
while i < len(arr):
  i += 1
  new_result = function(x)
  x = new_result
  b = np.array(x)
  arr = np.vstack((arr, b))
```

Comment: I want to avoid the loop.